# PHP mySQL JOIN to determine records that do not equal

Tags: php, mysql

The following query is designed to find records that do not equal corresponding elector IDs in another table..

```
SELECT *
  FROM electors,voting_intention
  WHERE  electors.ID != voting_intention.elector
```

This should return 1 record in this FIDDLE http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/0a4b1/10 but returns many and with duplicates. Obviously I am missing something. What?

Comment: Should you be getting the record for elector id 4? Also, your fiddle is currently set to Sql Server.

Comment: Yes because that is the only elector.ID that does not equal any voting_intention.elector

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to get all electors who do not have any corresponding 'voting intention' records, please try the following. I'm assuming you want all fields for that elector. If not, you need to select the columns of interest.

```
select * from 
electors where id not in 
(select elector from voting_intention)
```

Comment: Good but getting all occurences of the elector to so its producing only elector.ID 4 but 4 times as there are 4 voting_intention rows in the example on the fiddle.

Comment: Well, I'm only getting one record. You could use distinct to get just one row. Please have a look at http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ea2ce/1/0

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
  FROM voting_intention
  RIGHT JOIN electors ON electors.ID = voting_intention.elector
  WHERE  voting_intention.elector IS null
```